# Can't get data by using aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Server mongo version is 3.4.4.
Connected by Studio 3T.
When I query like this in IntelliShell

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $skip: 10 }
])
```

I get nothing returned.
However, when I switch the $limit and $skip,

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $skip: 10 },
    { $limit: 10 }
])
```

It works fine.

Comment: Well you did ask *"Get me just 10 results and then skip past 10 of them"*, so what else would you honestly expect? On the other hand, the second statement says *"Skip 10 results, and then return the next 10"*. So it's not hard to see how those are different when you phrase them semantically.

Comment: See also [$skip + $limit Sequence Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#skip-limit-sequence-optimization) which shows exactly how the sequence gets internally optimized and a direct example of why your first attempt fails. In short the second gets optimized to `{ $limit: 20 },{ $skip: 10 }`.

Comment: But why doesn't mongodb treat them as the same?

Comment: How have I not demonstrated to you that they are completely different? Get a deck of cards take out 10 and then throw those 10 away. This is what you asked the first time. How many cards do you have left from those you took out? Now take 20 cards off the deck and throw 10 away. This is the second one. How many cards do you have left in your hand? Pretty simple excercise

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding: 
The `$limit: 10` means 'I want ten result', 
and the `$skip` means 'I don't need the first tens'. 
So, I get 0 results by the first query, get 10-20 results by  the second query.